# Edit existing XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I want to edit edit existing XML file that is hosted on a URL. Is it possible ? if yes how can we get names of tags?
or we can generate new XML file as i know how many and which tags will exist,and replace the existing one

I have to use c# win forms to accomplish this task

Comment: If you have access via FTP, download it, change it and upload it again.

Comment: no other way i tried to use XML writer at mt wamp server that hosts xml file but exception occured "URI formats are not supported."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can using Linq to xml,when you start ,you will process XElement class and XDocument class.

Answer (score 0):

To modify the file you could use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx), then you have to replace the existing file accessing the website:

- via [FTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx), deleting the xml and uploading the new one;
- via [Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx), hosted in your website that helps you to upload the new file;

For the first solution you have to implement your own class or, alternatively, to use a free command line ftp uploader.
Anyway, I would prefer the second idea I gave you: in that way you'll have to write less code making it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://gregsxmleditor.codeplex.com/) is a open source project (desktop xml editor).